# How to use --use-features=in-tree-build option in a tox integration?

Tags: python, pip, continuous-integration, github-actions, tox

I am using `tox` in continuos integration (CI) in GitHub Actions. There seems to be an issue with it not using the `--use-features=in-tree-build` option that I would normally run when doing `pip install .` Is there are a way for me to include this `--use-features=in-tree-build` argument in the CI somewhere?

In the CI, all is run is `tox -e py` and then there is no configuration options in `pyproject.toml` for `[tox]`.
`

Comment: https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `tox` via `pyproject.toml`, cf https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#pyproject-toml-tox-legacy-ini

There you can use the already mentioned `install_command` to pass additional options to `pip`, see https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-install_command